Surface Deform "target contains invalid polygons"
I am trying to use the surface deform modifier but I keep getting errors. I initially got the error" target has edges with more than two polygons" but was able to fix it by selecting edges with multiple faces by selecting by trait - non-manifold and deleting the selected edges. Now the error says the target has "invalid polygons" and I have no idea how to fix it.
I've tried triangulating the mesh, but that doesn't work.

Hello could you please share your file?
